# Как поменять размер шрифта в DialogInterface

Tags: java, android

Создаю диалоговое окно с выбором. Как задать размер шрифта и другие настройки?

```
final String[] mMainName = {"Нов", "Со", "Др", "Ра", "Выйти"};
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setItems(mMainName, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)        {WorkMenu(item); } });
builder.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: сделать свою разметку для диалога

Comment: имеется ввиду сделать *.xml файл? А где его прописать потом?

Comment: да. и еще нужно сделать свой адаптер. посмотрите, как пример http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811117/custom-objects-in-alertdialog-list-how-to-get-a-display-string-and-then-the-act